# MX Record Cutover to Office 365

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

We recently migrated all of our mailboxes from Zimbra to Office 365, and we are currently running a split domain. I want to reconfigure my MX records to point to Office 365 while minimizing the chances of any mail sent to `ourdomain.org` being lost.

Here is my current setup:

ourdomain.org has two MX records configured that point to `ms1.ourdomain.org` and `ms2.ourdomain.org`, respectively. Both of these subdomains point to the same IP address, which is the address of our on-prem Zimbra server.

My plan is to point one MX record at `ourdomain.mail.protection.office365.us` and give it a higher priority than the second record, which will remain configured to point to `ms2.ourdomain.org` until the first record change propagates. We will make this change around midnight on a Saturday. If I understand correctly, this should start mail flowing directly to our Office 365 presence and bypass the Zimbra server completely, with the second MX record catching anything that might fall through the cracks (like DNS servers that ignore my TTL values). In theory, this should keep mail  flowing uninterrupted. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: The way this is usually done is that you have an ongoing synchronization process that syncs mail from the Zimbra server and populates the Office 365 mailboxes. Then, you simply update the MX records to point to Office 365, connect all users to Office 365 mailboxes, and let the synchronization process grab any remaining mail from Zimbra until the TTL of the DNS records expire and you’re sure no more mail is flowing to Zimbra. Typically you update the TTL of the MX records well in advance to be very short (5 min or whatever) then any changes are propagated within minutes during cutover.

Comment: There's no reason to keep the `IN MX mx2` in place. Every DNS server still having the old records will reply with it anyway.

Comment: Sounds like it will work, just be aware that the backup MX only comes into play when the primary isn't reachable, etc.  but not when a simple user-not-found occurs, so you'll need to ensure all of your addresses/aliases/etc are set up, first.